# Using field calculator if statement to update another field using another field's values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript, if-statement

Using VBA in field calculator I am trying to figure out the expression that if 3 conditions are met populate a field using another field's value and I cant get it to work! CALC_CLASS is a joined table and SPEED LIMIT is a Double type, MMS_TEMP is text.

[image]

I am using VBA and ARC 10.3

```
if [SPEED_LIMIT]=>91 and [SPEED_LIMIT] <= 100 and [MMS_TEMP]="53,000 or more" then
RD_BASELINE.CLASS_MMS= [CALC_CLASS_MMS.PSL_91_100]

elseif [SPEED_LIMIT]=>51 and [SPEED_LIMIT] <= 60 and [MMS_TEMP]="53,000 or more" then 
RD_BASELINE.CLASS_MMS= [CALC_CLASS_MMS.PSL_51_60]

else
RD_BASELINE.CLASS_MMS=[CALC_CLASS_MMS.PSL_1_40]                 

end if**
```

Comment: Your greater than or equal `=>` is incorrect. It should be `>=`.

Answer (score 3):

I think what is happening here is that you have entered all your worflow in the pre-logic script and then told the calculator that `RD_BASELINE.CLASS_MMS=RD_BASELINE.CLASS_MMS`, which doesn't mean anything. This pre-logic script is run BEFORE the operation takes place. To make this work, you need to define a function in the pre-logic script code, and then call that function using the expression. I don't code much in VB, but in python, I would try:

```
def calculate_answer(speed_limit, mms_temp, psl_91_100, psl_51_60, psl_1_40):
    if speed_limit >= 91 and speed_limit <= 100 and mms_temp == "53,000 or more":
        out = psl_91_100
    elif speed_limit >= 51 and speed_limit <= 60 and mms_temp =="53,000 or more":
        out = psl_51_60
    else:
        out = psl_1_40 
    return out
```

Then, in the expression field, just enter:

```
calculate_answer([SPEED_LIMIT], [MMS_TEMP], [CALC_CLASS_MMS.PSL_91_100],  [CALC_CLASS_MMS.PSL_51_60], [CALC_CLASS_MMS.PSL_1_40])
```

You can find lots VB examples for the field calculator [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm) if you want to stick to that language.

Comment: Your greater than or equal `=>` is incorrect. It should be `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to provide you an answer in Python:

open your Field Calculator and activate your show Codeblock:

[image]

Do not care about the field names since I am using a personal table. You can see the code in the picture but since last line is not showing I paste the code here:

```
def compare (SpeedLmt, MMS_Temp, AssignValue):
    if (SpeedLmt >= 92 and SpeedLmt <= 100  and MMS_Temp == 53000):
        return = "psl_91_100"
    elif (SpeedLmt >= 51 and SpeedLmt <= 60 and MMS_Temp == 53000):
        AssignValue = "psl_51_60"
    else:
        AssignValue = "AssignValue"
```

Then call the function in the AssignValu:

compare ( !SpeedLimit! ,  !MM_TEMP!, !AssignValu! )

Comment: Thanks Milad, However will the "psl_1_40" update via the values in the field or just simply add in psl_1_40 (text) into the MMS field?

Comment: It will add in "psl_1_40" if the two above conditions are not met. If you want to have more control (like assigning a certain value) based on a certain condition then we need to add another statement. Did I answer your question?

Comment: No Milad but thank you I am still looking for "update another field using another field's values" not simply assigning a text value.

Comment: I am assuming that you have created a field for psl_  so before applying the code there is nothing in that column. If you have already values for psl_ and you want to keep the ones non affected by the code you need to replace "psl_1_40" with the name of your variable so the code will return the same pre-stored value without changing it. Did I answer your question?

Comment: I updated the last line: `AssignValue = "AssignValue"` so you will get the pre-stored value.

Comment: This function will not work. Your `elif` and `else` statements assign a value to a variable, but the function does nothing with that variable. Also you have `AssignValue` listed as an input to the function but you seem to want to use it in the output.

Comment: Thank you @Dan for the explanation. Would you correct the code to make it work as demanded by the author? I am curious!